# cakephp change default action for controller (i.e. from “index”)

Tags: cakephp

I have some controllers I want to default to table and not index, as they present better in a different format than my index pages use. How can I change this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it. For others:

The file /app/config/routes.php contains the routing configuration, and default action can be changed there

```
Router::connect(
   '/pages',
   array('controller' => 'pages', 'action' => 'display')
);
```